# View and Model data formats

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**How do I define format of data to be used in View and Model?**

I clearly understand what ViewModel here is it to get data from Model, convert it (if necessary) and supply to the View (and in opposite direction):

> User <--> formatted data (converters) <--> View <--> **converted data** (to be used by generic View) <--> ViewModel <--> raw data <--> Model

Now what is my problem? I want to pass `OperationProgress` from Model to View:

```
class OperationStep
{
    string _name;
    bool _isError;
    int _time;
    ...
}

class OperationProgress
{
    List<OperationStep> _steps;
    OperationStep _currentStep;
    // int _currentStepIndex;
    int _currentStepTime;
    ...
}
```

ViewModel converts `OperationProgress` into a bunch of bindable properties (`List<bool>` of errors, current step name and time countdown) and View uses them (and converters!) to display progress to the User.

I am willing to create a specialized control to handle progress display, to avoid same repeatable **data conversion into primitive types** in ViewModels.

But I fail to figure out how to define data format for the control... Using `OperationProgress` in the `View` control directly (exposing it in the ViewModel and binding to it)? Creating `ControlProgress` (progress data specially for control)? But then what are benefits if ViewModel has to convert `OperationProgress` to `ControlProgress`? Using `ControlProgress` in Model (doesn't feels right).

So here I come. If you guys would do something similar (passing bunch of data, not just `string` or `int`, from Model to View or in opposite direction) how would you organize it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide weither you can live with simply a `DataTemplate` targetting your `OperationProgress` type, or if you have to create a full `MVVM` stack for `OperationProgress`. It depends on the complexity of the data, and the interaction with the data.

Edit:

You said :

> I am willing to create a specialized control to handle progress display, to avoid same repeatable data conversion into primitive types in ViewModels.

but what you want, as far as I understood, is not only a `Control`, but the full `MVVM` stack so that the conversion from  `OperationProgress` to `ControlProgress` is also encapsulated in your new VM.

So, what you call *"a specialized control to handle progress display"* would become `OperationProgressView`, and *"ControlProgress"* would become `OperationProgressViewModel`.

Comment: I want to create a *"very complex"* `UserControl` (with some bindable properties to bind to progress data given by `ViewModel`). `DataTemplate` might not do well if I need to combine it with code.

Comment: Then I think you should treat it as a normal `MVVM` stack (`OperationProgressView` / `OperationProgressViewModel`)

Comment: Perhaps I still think `winforms` way. I haven't thought about having dedicated ViewModel behind my control. Have to think about it. Can you illustrate how would having that ViewModel helps? Or perhaps own implementation if you would have progress (like mine `OperationProgress`) and have to show something to user without having ViewModel of window do conversion (which I am trying to avoid).

Comment: I see now, thanks. Sort of moving code from many ViewModels into one of that control.

Comment: Cool. One last thing : not *"one of that `Control`"*, but (sub) `ViewModel`. In `WPF/MVVM`, `Controls` are entities of the `View layer`.